# Adding Middle Button to Header in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I know that I can add buttons to the left and right of header in jquery mobile.. but how can I add a button in the "center" area...?

[like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS6Vc.png)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<button id="middleButton">Main Page</button>
```

And then, in CSS, use this.

```
<style>
button.middleButton {
    position : relative;/*This makes you able to move the button*\
    bottom: 300;/* will move up 300px*\
    top: 300;/*will move down 300px*\
    left: 300;/*will move right 300px*\
    right: 300;/*will move left 300px*\
</style>
```

Hope this helped!